# Why doesn't (Xine, VLC, etc) work on MythTV 0.22 and later?

Tags: mythtv, mythbuntu

I used to be able to use an external player for video playback, but now that I have updated MythTV I no longer have that option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Recent versions of MythTV default to using Storage Groups. External players do not work when using Storage Groups. See [MythVideo - Disadvantages](http://www.mythtv.org/wiki/MythVideo#Disadvantages)